# Limit HTTP POST size for form submission

Tags: python, html, cgi

Let's say I have a simple HTML webpage (served using apache) as

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="CGI script test">
        <meta name="keywords" content="test">
        <meta name="author" content="cgi test">
        <title> CGI Script Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/cgi-bin/submit.py" method="POST">
            <label for="entry">Entry name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="entry" name="entryname" placeholder="placeholder" maxlength="10">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

where data submitted in the form is processed using submit.py, a python script (placed in my cgi-bin directory) as

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi,re

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("<title>Hello World</title>")
print("<h1>HELLO</h1>")

text=str(form.getvalue("entryname"))

print("<p> Parsing result...</p>")

result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9:@#/-_,]', ' ', text)

print("<h3> Resulting Info: </h3>")
print("<p>" + str(result) + "</p>")`
```

I want to avoid my server getting stuffed with POSTs that are excessively long.  If I load the HTML webpage above, I can use the "inspect element" tool in firefox to delete the "maxlength" requirement and stuff in as much information as I want.  The python script then receives the full input text.  This is my first website and I want to make sure I do this right.  Is there a limit to the size of the POST sent to the server, and if not, how do I limit it to prevent abuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can examine [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header and compare it with a limit. [`cgitb.enable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) should be helpful with displaying errors when the limit is reached.

```py
import cgitb
import os


MAX_POST_BODY_SIZE = 1024

cgitb.enable(display=0)

content_length = int(os.getenv('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
if content_length > MAX_POST_BODY_SIZE:
    raise RuntimeError('POST body too long')
```

### Update 1

I've looked into `cgi` module's code and it seems POST body size limiting is actually [implemented in `FieldStorage`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83d1430e/Lib/cgi.py#L467-L473) but it's not documented. There's [`cgi.maxlen`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83d1430ee5b8008631e7f2a75447e740eed065c1/Lib/cgi.py#L117-L119) attribute:

```py
# Maximum input we will accept when REQUEST_METHOD is POST
# 0 ==> unlimited input
maxlen = 0
```

Hence, it should be just:

```
import cgi
import cgitb

cgi.maxlen = 1024
cgitb.enable(display=0)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

> [...] would the server still have to allocate memory to receive the full post?

As far as I can see in the initialiser of `FieldStorage` the steps are as follows:

1. [`fp` is assigned](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83d1430e/Lib/cgi.py#L406), `self.fp = sys.stdin.buffer`
2. `Content-Length` is [validated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83d1430e/Lib/cgi.py#L467-L473)
3. when then `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  [`read_urlencoded` is called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/83d1430e/Lib/cgi.py#L480-L481) which reads `Content-Length` bytes from the instance's `fp` attribute.

To test it with your CGI server, send a big request and look at `htop` or other process monitor for the CGI process' memory usage.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

urlopen(
    'http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/submit.py', 
    data=b'entryname=%s' % (b'abcd' * 2  ** 24),  # 64 MiB
)
```

Comment: Does this still require that the server receive the full message?  Say for example `content_length=180000000` and `MAX_POST_BODY_SIZE=1024`, obviously it would return 'POST body too long', but would the server still have to allocate memory to receive the full post?

Comment: Confirmed with curl: this does appear to limit the message size: `curl -X POST -F "entryname=@test.txt" example.com/cgi-bin/submit.py`
`curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` thanks!